# How can I only read in the first line of a file in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, file, csv

I am trying to read only the first line of a CSV file in javascript without reading the entire file. So far, the solutions I've found on SO only include using .split which still reads in the entire file and splits by newlines. I've also tried using FileReader progress to stop after the first line, but you can't control how much is read in progress. How could I go about using progress or another method to only get the first line and not read in the rest of the file?

Comment: You are going to have to load the whole file. What is the code you are currently using to load the file?

Comment: Could I read in character by character and then stop at a newline?

Comment: Is this code run in the browser, or in node.js?

Comment: Again, how are you loading the file?

Answer (score 0):

There are published libraries that allow line-by-line reading of a file.

In the browser, there is [line-navigator](https://github.com/anpur/line-navigator):

```js
var navigator = new LineNavigator(file[, options]);

navigator.readLines(indexToStartWith, numberOfLines,
  function (err, index, lines, isEof, progress) {
    // handle result here
  });
```

In node.js, there is [line-reader](https://github.com/nickewing/line-reader):

```js
var lineReader = require('line-reader');

// read line by line:
lineReader.open('file.txt', function(err, reader) {
  if (err) throw err;
  if (reader.hasNextLine()) {
    reader.nextLine(function(err, line) {
      try {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log(line);
      } finally {
        reader.close(function(err) {
          if (err) throw err;
        });
      }
    });
  }
  else {
    reader.close(function(err) {
      if (err) throw err;
    });
  }
});
```